# What is the standard way to send data to the view on Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

Is there a standarized way to send data to the window on Electron? I mean, I do know it is *possible* to do so, but what's the **recommended** or at least **the most used way** to do it?

Also, is it recommended to have, for instance, an Express server running with the Electron app to fetch the data needed?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the most (and only?) way to transmit data between the window and the main process is using **ipcMain** and **ipcRenderer**, here's the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main).

Basically, this is how it works:

**index.js**

```js
// You create your browserWindow element here
let win = new BrowserWindow()

// and to send data from your Main to your Renderer, you can do the following once the dom is ready:
win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    // Send some data to your browser window
    win.webContents.send('data', 'hello world')
})
```

Notice that requiring ipcMain isn't needed to **send** data to renderer, but only to receive them.

And on the other side, in **renderer.js**, you can handle your data using the following:

```js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data: ${data}`)
    // Outputs 'Reveived data: Hello world'
})
```

If you need to send data from renderer to main, it is basically the same, here is an example:
**renderer.js**

```js
ipcRenderer.send('otherData', 'Hey, I am the browser')
```

and on **index.js** side:

```js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('otherData', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data: ${data}`)
    // Displays: 'Received data: Hey, I am the browser'
})
```